# Can't find common super class of android/webkit/WebView (with 5 known super classes) and com/yandex/metrica/impl/ob/Il

Tags: java, android, kotlin, signed-apk

I was trying to generate a signed apk but an error occurred :

Can't find a common superclass of [android/WebKit/WebView] (with 5 known superclasses) and [com/yandex/metrica/impl/ob/Il] (with 1 known super classes).

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Refer to below screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te26R.png

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Actually i was trying to generate a signed apk but encountered with an error of can’t find common classes of webView and Yandex.metrica as mentioned

Comment: Please, provide some screenshots of your errors or you can attach Logcat.

Comment: Can't find common super class of [android/webkit/WebView] (with 5 known super classes) and [com/yandex/metrica/impl/ob/Il] (with 1 known super classes)

end up with this in build output.

Comment: Screenshot link also added

Comment: Please help me out in this, I have also tried cloning the project again.